# How I can rotate touch screen input device to match the dipslay rotation (flip) in Ubuntu 22.04 (wayland)

Tags: 22.04, touchscreen, wayland, libinput

Ubuntu 22.04 uses wayland, and I have touchscreen monitor that is rotated to 180 degree. Rotating the picture was easy (in settings -> displays). But the touch input did not rotate.

How I can map the input device to that monitor and rotate (flip) the touch input to match the rotation.